# Function to rename argument in Vim

Tags: javascript, vim, arguments, rename

I am learning VIM through use, and I couldn't find something that directly relates to my need.

I would like to quickly rename an argument in my function.

```js
function( a_fuz, a_roh, a_baz ) {
    return a_fuz + a_roh + a_baz;
}
```

By selecting `a_baz` and calling my function, I would like to type `a_dah` and replace all occurrences of the word `a_baz` inside the function body (and also at the header of the code).

I have a function like the one bellow in my `vimrc` file:

```vim
function RenameArg()
    let l_word = expand('<cword>')
    let l_replace = input('Name: ')
    " Moves the cursor to the definition, then to the next open bracket
    " character. Then, it selects the whole brackets pair
    execute "normal gdV/{/e\<CR>%"
    " Performs a substitution of the words inside the selected area

    " For debugging purposes
    " echomsg "\'<,\'>s/\\<" . l_word . "\\>/" . l_replace
    execute "\'<,\'>s/\\<" . l_word . "\\>/" . l_replace
endfunction
```

I am not very sure of what is wrong here. When I run both `execute`s separately, it works. But When I call my function, it appears to be selecting only the first line.

**EDIT**

This is the current version for the functions to rename arguments and local variables (there are problems when `gd` identifies results that are should not be matched. Also, it is using brackets as the delimiter for positioning):

```vim
"Renames an argument from a function
function RenameArg()
    let l_word = expand('<cword>')
    let l_replace = input('Name: ')
    " Moves the cursor to the definition, then to the next open bracket
    " character. Then, it selects the whole brackets pair
    normal gd
    execute "normal V/{/e\<CR>%:s/\\<" . l_word . "\\>/" . l_replace . "\<CR>"
endfunction

"Renames a variable local to the current scope.
function RenameLocal()
    let l_word = expand('<cword>')
    let l_replace = input('Name: ')
    " Moves the cursor to the definition, then to the next open bracket
    " character. Then, it selects the whole brackets pair
    normal gd
    execute "normal V[{%:s/\\<" . l_word . "\\>/" . l_replace . "\<CR>"
endfunction
```

Comment: Well, I am using the command substitute at the very bottom of my function. Is there any resource in particular of the substitute function in your mind?

Comment: Opps... I missed that... But your quoting looks suspicious. Why do you escape the single quote in the range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably fix this by just doing the `:s` with your `:norm`.

```
execute "normal gdV/{/e\<CR>%:s//" . l_replace . "\<cr>"
```

You may want to skip the custom function and use the `gn` motion. example:

```
gdcgna_dah<esc>
```

This will change your argument to `a_dah`. The best part is you can just keep pressing `.` to repeat the change on each instance. '

Explanation:

- `gd` go to definition
- `cgn` change the matched text`
- `a_dah<esc>` the new text and escape to normal mode
- `.` repeat the change

Note: `gn` requires Vim 7.4

For more help see:

```
:h :norm
:h :exe
:h gn
:h .
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! After doing this change, it worked: `execute "normal gdV/{/e\<CR>%:s/\\<" . l_word . "\\>/" . l_replace . "\<CR>"`

Comment: Also, thanks for letting me know about gn. It will came in handy, for sure .